# Is possibile to define an exponentiation with respect an ordinal operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, set-theory, recursion, ordinals

It is well know the following resul holds.

> **Theorem**
>
> For any $(M,\bot,e)$ monoid there exists a unique esternal operation $\wedge_\ast$ from $X\times\omega$ into $X$ such that for any $x$ in $M$ the following results hold:
>
> 1. the equality
>    $$
>      x\curlywedge_\bot 0=e
>      $$
> 2. the equality holds
>    $$
>     x\curlywedge_\bot(n+1)=(x\curlywedge_\bot n)\bot x
>     $$
>    for any $n$ in $\omega$.

So let's we call $\curlywedge_\bot$ exponentiation of $\curlywedge_\bot$ so that let's we observe that the usual multiplication into $\omega$ is just the exponentiation of the usual summ. So observing the definition of ordinal multiplication I advanced the following conjecture: to follow I indicate the ordinal class with the symbol $\mathbf{Ord}$ whereas I indicate the limit ordinal class with the symbol $\mathbf{Lim}$.

> **Conjecture**
>
> Let $\bot$ be an operation on $\mathbf{Ord}$ with a neutral element $\mu$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$. Then there exists a unique operation $\curlywedge_\bot$ on $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that for every $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$, the following statements hold:
>
> 1. $\alpha\curlywedge_\bot 0 = \mu$
> 2. $\alpha\curlywedge_\bot(\beta+1)=(\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\beta)\bot\alpha$ for every $\beta\in\mathbf{Ord}$
> 3. $\alpha\curlywedge\beta=\sup_{\gamma\in\beta}(\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\gamma)$ for every $\beta\in\mathbf{Lim}$ not empty.

So is the above conjecture true? if it is ture then how to prove it? can I prove it with recursion? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: This is a valid definition of $\wedge_*$ by transfinite recursion. You would prove that $\wedge_*$ is the unique operation satisfying these properties by transfinite induction.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I tried to use parametric recursion but I was not able to implementing it and in particular I just tried use that recursion which distinguish between successor and limit ordinals: so have you some ideas about?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think I found a possibile solution using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By examining accurately the existence proof of sum I elaborated by my self what to follow.*

Let us first recall the following theorem: to follow we will indicate with $\mathbf{Ord}$ the class of ordinals and with $\mathbf{Lim}$ the class of limit ordinals.

> **Theorem $0$**
>
> If $\mathbf F$, $\mathbf G$, and $\mathbf H$ are functionals, then there exists a unique functional $\Psi$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that the following statements hold:
>
> - $\Psi(\emptyset)$ equals $\mathbf F(\emptyset)$;
> - $\Psi\big(S(\alpha)\big)$ equals $\mathbf G\big(\Psi(\alpha)\big)$ for every $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$;
> - $\Psi(\lambda)$ equals $\mathbf H(\Psi\restriction_\lambda)$ for every non-empty $\lambda$ in $\mathbf{Lim}$.

Now, armed with Theorem $0$, let's we prove the following important and useful result.

> **Theorem $1$**
>
> For every operation $\bot$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ with a neutral element $\mu$, there exists a unique binary operation $\curlywedge_\bot$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that the following statements hold for every $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$:
>
> 1. $\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\emptyset=\mu$
> 2. $\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\operatorname{succ}\beta=(\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\beta)\bot\alpha$ for every $\beta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$
> 3. $\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\beta=\sup_{\gamma\in\beta}(\alpha\curlywedge_\bot\gamma)$ for every non-empty $\beta$ in $\mathbf{Lim}$

> *Proof.*
>
> Let $\mathbf F$, $\mathbf G$, and $\mathbf H$ be predicates of one parameter $x$, one parameter $y$ and one parameter $z$ defined as follows
>
> - $\mathbf F(x,y,z)$ is true if $z$ is $\mu$;
> - $\mathbf G(x,y,z)$ is true if $z$ is $y\bot x$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbf{Ord}$, or if $z$ is the empty set otherwise;
> - $\mathbf H(x,y,z)$ is true if $z$ is $\bigcup\operatorname{ran}y$ whenever $y$ is a function, or if $z$ is the empty set otherwise.
>
> Now, if $\Phi$ is a property of one parameter $x$, one parameter $y$ and one parameter $z$ then for some entity $a$ let be $\Phi_a$ the property of one parameter $b$ and one parameter $c$ such that $\Phi_a$ holds if and only if $\Phi(a,b,c)$ holds: so for some entity $x$ let's we observe that the predicates $\mathbf F_x$, $\mathbf G_x$, and $\mathbf H_x$ are functionals. Thus, by Theorem $0$, for every $\theta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ there exists a function $\Psi_\theta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that the following statements hold:
>
> a. $\Psi_\theta(\emptyset)=\mathbf F_\theta(\emptyset)$;
>
> b. $\Psi_\theta(\operatorname{succ}\delta)=\mathbf G_\theta\big(\Psi_\theta(\delta)\big)$ for every $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$
>
> c. $\Psi_\theta(\delta)=\mathbf H_\theta(\Psi_\theta\restriction_\delta)$ for every non-empty $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Lim}$.
>
> Now, let us prove that the definition
> $$
> \Psi(\theta,\delta):=\Psi_\theta(\delta)
> \tag{$\alpha$}
> \label{def: esponenziazione ordinale}
> $$
> with $\theta$ and $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ defines a function in $\mathbf{Ord}$ such that statements $1$-$3$ hold.
>
> Since $\Psi_\theta(\delta)$ is unique for $\theta$ and $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$, clearly, def. \eqref{def: esponenziazione ordinale} defines a function in $\mathbf{Ord}$. Thus, by statement (a), we observe that
> $$
> \Psi(\theta,\emptyset)=\Psi_\theta(\emptyset)=\mathbf F_\theta(\emptyset)=\mu
> \tag{$\beta$}
> \label{eq: /Psi(/theta,/emptyset)=/emptyset}
> $$
> for every $\theta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$; furthermore, by statement (b), we observe that
> $$
> \Psi(\theta,\operatorname{succ}\delta)=\Psi_\theta(\operatorname{succ}\delta)=\mathbf G_\theta\big(\Psi_\theta(\delta)\big)=\Psi_\theta(\delta)\bot\theta=\Psi(\theta,\delta)\bot\theta
>                 \tag{$\gamma$}
>    \label{eq: /Psi(/theta,/succ/delta)=/Psi(/theta,/delta)/oplus/theta}
> $$
> for every ordinal $\theta$ and $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$; finally, if $\theta$ is an ordinal, then by the Replacement Axiom, $\Psi_\theta\restriction_\delta$ is a function for every $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$ and thus, by st. (c), we conclude that
> $$
>  \Psi(\theta,\delta)=\Psi_\theta(\delta)=\mathbf H_\theta(\Psi_\theta\restriction_\delta)=\bigcup(\operatorname{ran}\Psi_\theta\restriction_\delta)=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\delta}\Psi_\theta(\lambda)=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\delta}\Psi(\theta,\lambda)
>                 \tag{$\delta$}
>    \label{eq: /Psi(/theta,/succ/delta)=/Psi(/theta,/delta)/oplus/theta esponenziazione}
> $$
> for every non-empty $\delta$ in $\mathbf{Lim}$.
>
> Well, by equations \eqref{eq: /Psi(/theta,/emptyset)=/emptyset} - \eqref{eq: /Psi(/theta,/succ/delta)=/Psi(/theta,/delta)/oplus/theta esponenziazione}, we conclude that statements $1$-$3$ are true with respect to $\Psi$.
>
> Now, if $\Phi$ is a functional for which statements $1$-$3$ are true then it is not difficult to conclude (it is sufficient to distinguish the case where $\beta$ is empty, successor and limit) the equality
> $$
>   \Psi(\alpha,\beta)=\Phi(\alpha,\beta)
>   $$
> holds for every $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbf{Ord}$. Therefore, by setting
> $$
>   \Psi:=\curlywedge_\bot
>   $$
> the statement follows.